# My app keeps crashing at the following point (see code) with a [NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My app keeps crashing at the following point (see code) with an error:

> [NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument.

After the login, if successful, it should download video to my site. This was working fine until I upgraded the version of Xcode. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong with the code or why it started to happen?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![standardDefaults objectForKey:@"login"]) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" message:@"You need an account before you can do that. Register now or Sign In if your an existing member:)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Sign In",@"No Thanks", nil] show];
    }
    else{
        NSString *strLogin = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"login"]];
        if (![strLogin isEqualToString:@"yes"])
        {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi there" message:@"You need an account before you can do that. Register now for free :)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Register",@"No Thanks", nil] show];
        }

//I believe it is crashing at this point ---
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.urlArray count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"URLcount is %lu",(unsigned long)[self.urlArray count]);
            videoURL = [self.urlArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [self saveToCameraRoll];
        }

    }

}

Here is my saveToCameraRoll

- (void) saveToCameraRoll {

    [self showProgressHud];

    videodata= [[NSData alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"];
    strDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    NSLog(@"videoURL is is is is %@",videoURL);
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL.path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    videodata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];


    NSRange needleRange = NSMakeRange([videoURL.path length]- 21, 21);
    filename = [videoURL.path substringWithRange:needleRange];
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *strId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"]];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/video-save.php"]]];
    [request setPostValue:strId forKey:@"userid"];
    [request setPostValue:@"2015-04-18 : 16:00" forKey:@"date"];
    [request setData:videodata  forKey:@"videofile"];


    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60.0];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startAsynchronous];


}
```

Comment: Which line of code exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Please set symbolic breakpoint and post here exact code lines where app stops.

Comment: I believe it is crashing -- starting with this section of code or when it makes the call to [saveToCameraRoll]     
----------->>
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.urlArray count]; i++) {
         NSLog(@"URLcount is %lu",(unsigned long)[self.urlArray count]);
         videoURL = [self.urlArray objectAtIndex:i];
         [self saveToCameraRoll];

Comment: Here is what is printed out on the log.  Since I had a successful login, I am only guessing it is occurring right after that.

request info {"status":{"status":"200"},"userInfo":{"userID":"17","username":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com"}}
2017-01-02 21:34:22.935203 myApp [565:285787] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x183c891b8 0x1826c055c 0x183c89100 0x1846b8eb8 0x100168380 0x100148008 0x18479d048 0x183c36b5c 0x183c364a4 0x183c340a4 0x183b622b8 0x185616198 0x189ba97fc 0x189ba4534 0x10013cb70 0x182b455b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This what I see in the debug window:
arg = (int) 1
arg = (char **) 0x16fd33938
  *argv = (char *) /var/containers/Bundle/Application/899A6736-1AE3-4156-9
    **argv = (char) ‘/‘

Comment: This is the area it crashed:
    0x10016cb6c <+120>: bl     0x1001a5c54               ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
    0x10016cb70 <+124>: stur   w0, [x29, #-4]

Answer (score 0):

the issue was invoked from this line

```
NSString *strId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"]];
```

I figured that the key @"user_id" returns nil object. if you try the code

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithString:nil];
```

you'll end up with the same error.

Comment: thank you.  Although, I do not follow how it is returning a nil object.  After the login I get:   {"status":{"status":"200"},"userInfo":{"userID":"17","username":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com"}}   It looks like it has a UserID object.

Comment: please make sure you saved "userID" into NSUserDefaults as key @"user_id"; it was more probably you stored the value of key @"userInfo" into NSUserDefaults as a whole, but not "userID" "username" separately.